Can we make a text-to-speech function from a push notification in Swift?
Currently, I'm working on a project to implement text-to-speech functionality when the app receives a push notification. The notification is saved locally and shown using a local notification with UNMutableNotificationContent() for the content. It has to use the ringer audio and must run in the foreground, background, and even when the app is killed, similar to the .sound property in UNMutableNotificationCenter().
I am specifically not using the playback category in AVAudioSession because it uses media audio instead of ringer audio. When I use the ambient category in AVAudioSession, it cannot run in the background or when the app is killed. I expect it to run in the foreground, background, and even when the app is killed upon receiving a push notification.
This code snippet is the logic I used in AppDelegate didReceiveRemoteNotification.
if let tts = userInfo["text"] as? String {
    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient,
                                    options: [.duckOthers])
    } catch {
        print("Unable to set audio session category: %@", error)
    }

    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: userInfo["text"] as! String)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "id-ID")
    synthesizer.speak(utterance)
}


The answer is quite likely no. Push notifications offer a certain very limited set of options. You can display an alert, with an image from your app. You can play a pre-recorded sound (also from your app bundle if memory serves.) You can display a banner with a title and a body. That's it. Once the user taps the notification your app launches and moves to the foreground and you have more options, but before, you can't interact with the user in custom ways.

The answer is probably no. Push notifications provide a limited range of options. You can display an alert with an image from your app, play a pre-recorded sound (also from your app bundle), or show a banner with a title and a message. That's about it. Once the user taps on the notification, your app launches and comes to the foreground, giving you more options to interact with the user. However, before the user engages with the notification, you can't customize interactions beyond the basic options provided.
